# How to model time-varying probability in Markov process with multinomial logistic regression?

Tags: r, markov-process, multinomial-logit

I have multiple discrete time Markov processes. They each consist of the same 12 categorical states. I want to model how the probability of each of these states varies over time across each process. To do this, I fit a multinomial logistic regression model with this formula:

State <sub>t+1</sub> ~ State <sub>t</sub> + Time

My data is organized like so:

| Subject | Time | State <sub>t</sub> | State <sub>t+1</sub> |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

There are multiple subjects in this dataset. Each subject has its own Markov process that is indexed by time at regular intervals from t=2 to t=600. In other words, each subject has its own series of state transitions, and each state transition for each subject has a corresponding time point that ranges from t=2 to t=600.

The multinomial logistic regression model seemed to have worked. It appears as if its fitted values can be used to represent how the probability of each state varies over time. However, I'm unsure if I fit this model correctly. For instance, I defined time as an integer rather than as, say, an ordered categorical variable. I'm not sure if this was the correct choice.

But, overall, I'd like to know whether I used this model appropriately.